# Advice on combining or coordinating multiple python scripts

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am still somewhat of a Python novice and am working on a raspberrypi based project at the moment.

I have successfully created and tested two (fairly simple) scripts which work well independently.
Script 1: continually scans for specific BLE devices and decodes the manufacturer data from the advert.
Script 2: continually reads data from a html page and decodes.

The raspberrypi passes all of the relevant information onto an HMI via a RS232 serial link. The HMI is limited in the fact it needs to receive all of the information from both scripts in the same message so I need to repeatedly send a data string with all of the info in. Script 2 contributes the first two parts of the string, script 2 contributes the remaining 20 parts of the string.

As you can see, the scripts currently have a small section at the end which sends the serial data from that script.

As I want to prevent too much lag between the info being received and processed and cannot predict when the data will be received, I don't think combining into a single large file will work as I will end up potentially missing data (e.g. the BLE data being sent). So I am assuming I need to run both scripts in the background and keep updating the relevant variables internally, then running a third script which reads them and collates them and sends the serial data?

**Script 1:**

```
`#! /usr/bin/python3 -u
import serial
import struct
from time import *
from bluepy.btle import Scanner

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)  #define serial port (PiZero 
onboard UART)
coding = "Windows-1252"

SENSORS = {"80:ea:ca:12:23:0b": "Front Left Tyre:" ,"81:ea:ca:22:20:f7" : "Front Right Tyre:", "82:ea:ca:32:24:87" : "Rear Left Tyre:", "83:ea:ca:42:23:07" : "Rear Right Tyre:"}

scanner = Scanner()

#set starting values for all output variables
pres_fl = pres_fr = pres_rl = pres_rr = ""
temp_fl = temp_fr = temp_rl = temp_rr = ""
batt_fl = batt_fr = batt_rl = batt_rr   = ""
status_fl = status_fr = status_rl = status_rr = "NONE"
flat_fl = flat_fr = flat_rl = flat_rr = "00"

front_min_pres = 30  # minimum pressure front psi
rear_min_pres = 30 # minimum pressure rear psi
max_temp = 50 # maximum temperature degC
min_batt = 30 # minimum battery level %
max_loss = 5

fl_count = 0
fr_count = 0
rl_count = 0
rr_count = 0

def sort_data(input_data):
  #read the relevant bytes fromt he array to each parameter
  id_byte =  chunks[2:8]
  pres_byte = chunks[8:12]
  temp_byte = chunks[12:16]
  batt_byte = chunks[16]
  flat_byte = chunks[17]

 #join the elements of each of the sub-arrays into a string
  id_str = ''.join(id_byte)
  pres_str = ''.join(pres_byte)
  temp_str = ''.join(temp_byte)
  
#convert strings into bytes from hex
  pres_hex = bytes.fromhex(pres_str)
  temp_hex = bytes.fromhex(temp_str)

#convert each bytes into integers
  pres_int = int.from_bytes(pres_hex,'little')
  temp_int = int.from_bytes(temp_hex,'little', signed=True)
  batt_int = int(batt_byte, 16)

#convert into strings and do necessary unit conversions
  pres = str(round(((pres_int/100000)*14.5),1))
  temp = str(round((temp_int/100),1))
  batt = str(batt_int)
  return (id_str , pres , temp , batt , flat_byte)
  
 def check(input_pres,input_temp,input_batt):
  input_pres = float(input_pres)
  input_temp = float(input_temp)
  input_batt = float(input_batt)
       
  if "Front" in device_location:
    if input_pres <= front_min_pres:
      status = "LOW PRESSURE"
    elif input_temp >= max_temp:
      status = "HIGH TEMP"
    elif input_batt <= min_batt:
      status = "LOW BATTERY"
    else:
      status = "OKAY"

  elif "Rear" in device_location:
    if input_pres <= rear_min_pres:
      status = "LOW PRESSURE"
    elif input_temp >= max_temp:
      status = "HIGH TEMP"
    elif input_batt <= min_batt:
      status = "LOW BATTERY"
    else:
      status = "OKAY"

  return status

while True:
  scan_entries = scanner.scan(2.0)

  #Scan for listed BLE devices and retrieve manufacturer info
  for scan_entry in scan_entries:
    if scan_entry.addr in SENSORS:
      device_location = SENSORS[scan_entry.addr]
      manufacturer_hex = next(value for _, desc, value in 
scan_entry.getScanData() if desc == 'Manufacturer')
      manufacturer_bytes = bytes.fromhex(manufacturer_hex)
 
     # Move manufacturer info into an array of x00 chunks
      chunk_length = 2
      chunks = [manufacturer_hex[i:i+chunk_length] for i in range(0, len(manufacturer_hex), chunk_length)] # combine data into an array
        
      id_str , pres , temp , batt , flat_byte = sort_data(chunks) 
  
      if flat_byte == "00":

       if id_str == "80eaca12230b":
         fl_count = 0
         position = "FL Tyre" 
         pres_fl = pres
         temp_fl = temp
         batt_fl = batt
         status_fl = check(pres,temp,batt)
         flat_fl = flat_byte
     
         fr_count = fr_count + 1
         if fr_count >= max_loss:
         status_fr = "LOST"
         rl_count = rl_count + 1
         if rl_count >= max_loss:
          status_rl = "LOST"
         rr_count = rr_count + 1
         if rr_count >= max_loss:
          status_rr = "LOST"
      
    
   elif id_str == "81eaca2220f7":
     fr_count = 0
     position = "FR Tyre"
     pres_fr = pres
     temp_fr = temp
     batt_fr = batt
     status_fr = check(pres,temp,batt)
     flat_fr = flat_byte
     
     fl_count = fl_count + 1
     if fl_count >= max_loss:
      status_fl = "LOST"
     rl_count = rl_count + 1
     if rl_count >= max_loss:
      status_rl = "LOST"
     rr_count = rr_count + 1
     if rr_count >= max_loss:
      status_rr = "LOST"

   elif id_str == "82eaca322487":
     rl_count = 0
     position = "RL Tyre"
     pres_rl = pres
     temp_rl = temp
     batt_rl = batt
     status_rl = check(pres,temp,batt)
     flat_rl = flat_byte
     
     fl_count = fl_count + 1
     if fl_count >= max_loss:
      status_fl = "LOST"         
     fr_count = fr_count + 1
     if fr_count >= max_loss:
      status_fr = "LOST"
     rr_count = rr_count + 1
     if rr_count >= max_loss:
      status_rr = "LOST"       
      
   elif id_str == "83eaca422307":
     rr_count = 0
     position = "RR Tyre"
     pres_rr = pres
     temp_rr = temp
     batt_rr = batt
     status_rr = check(pres,temp,batt)
     flat_rr = flat_byte  

     fl_count = fl_count + 1
     if fl_count >= max_loss:
      status_fl = "LOST"         
     fr_count = fr_count + 1
     if fr_count >= max_loss:
      status_fr = "LOST"
     rl_count = rl_count + 1
     if rl_count >= max_loss:
      status_rl = "LOST"                
 
   trip_ser = bytes("TRIP NAME," + "TRIP VALUE,", coding)
   pres_ser = bytes(pres_fl + "," + pres_fr + "," + pres_rl + "," + pres_rr + ",", coding)
   temp_ser = bytes(temp_fl + "," + temp_fr + "," + temp_rl + "," + temp_rr + ",", coding)
   batt_ser = bytes(batt_fl + "," + batt_fr + "," + batt_rl + "," + batt_rr + ",", coding)
   flat_ser = bytes(flat_fl + "," + flat_fr + "," + flat_rl + "," + flat_rr + ",", coding)
   status_ser = bytes(status_fl + "," + status_fr + "," + status_rl + "," + status_rr, coding)
   terminator = bytes("\r", coding)
   textstr = trip_ser + pres_ser + temp_ser + batt_ser + flat_ser + status_ser + terminator
   ser.write(textstr)
   print(textstr.decode(coding))
   print("FL:" + str(fl_count))
   print("FR:" + str(fr_count))
   print("RL:" + str(rl_count))
   print("RR:" + str(rr_count))       
   sleep(0)
                        
  else:
   status = "PUNCTURE"
  
   if id_str == "80eaca12230b":
     position = "FL Tyre"
     pres_fl = pres
     temp_fl = temp
     batt_fl = batt
     status_fl = status
     flat_fl = flat_byte
    
   elif id_str == "81eaca2220f7":
     position = "FR Tyre"
     pres_fr = pres
     temp_fr = temp
     batt_fr = batt
     status_fr = status
     flat_fr = flat_byte

   elif id_str == "82eaca322487":
     position = "RL Tyre"
     pres_rl = pres
     temp_rl = temp
     batt_rl = batt
     status_rl = status
     flat_rl = flat_byte

   elif id_str == "83eaca422307":
     position = "RR Tyre"
     pres_rr = pres
     temp_rr = temp
     batt_rr = batt
     status_rr = status
     flat_rr = flat_byte   
 
   trip_ser = bytes(",,", coding) # **These two parts need to come from script 2**
   pres_ser = bytes(pres_fl + "," + pres_fr + "," + pres_rl + "," + pres_rr + ",", coding)
   temp_ser = bytes(temp_fl + "," + temp_fr + "," + temp_rl + "," + temp_rr + ",", coding)
   batt_ser = bytes(batt_fl + "," + batt_fr + "," + batt_rl + "," + batt_rr + ",", coding)
   flat_ser = bytes(flat_fl + "," + flat_fr + "," + flat_rl + "," + flat_rr + ",", coding)
   status_ser = bytes(status_fl + "," + status_fr + "," + status_rl + "," + status_rr + ",", coding)
   terminator = bytes("\r", coding)
   textstr = trip_ser + pres_ser + temp_ser + batt_ser + flat_ser + status_ser + terminator
   ser.write(textstr)
   print(textstr.decode(coding))
   `
```

**Script 2**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3 -u
import urllib.request , time , serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)

#List of Charactors to remove from the message
bad_chars = ['{' , '":' , ' "' , '}' , '"']

format = "Windows-1252"

#-----------------Functions----------------------------
#Decode the incoming serial datastream
def decode_serial(input1):
    output1 = input1.decode(format).replace('\r','').replace('\n','') #decode the data and remove the \n & \n charactors
    return (output1)

#Convert fuel economy value to mpg
def convert_economy(input2):
    input2 = float(input2)
    output2 = round((input2 * 282.481),1)
    output2 = str(output2)
    return (output2)

#Convert speed value to mph
def convert_speed(input3):
    input3 = float(input3)
    output3 = round((input3 * 0.6214))
    output3 = str(output3)
    return (output3)

#Convert KPa value to bar
def convert_pres(input5):
    input5 = float(input5)
    output5 = (input5 / 100)
    output5 = str(output5)
    return (output5)

#------------------Main Program----------------------------
while True:
    
    # If there is a connection to the host:
    try: 
        data =  urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.4.1/readVal").read()

    #turn data into a string
        decode =  data.decode()
    #remove bad characters from string
        for i in bad_chars:
            decode = decode.replace(i,'')

    #split into list (comma seperated)
        list = decode.split(",")

    #assign to each type
        name_raw = list[0]
        value_raw = list[1]
        unit_raw = list[2]

    #remove superflous characters
        name = name_raw.replace("n","", 1)
        value = value_raw.replace("v","")
        value = value.replace('<br />',"  ")
        unit = unit_raw.replace("u","")

        #Carry out name , value & unit conversion if Turbo Boost is received
        if name == 'Turbo boost':
            name = 'Turbo Boost'
            unit = 'bar'
            value = convert_pres(value)

        #If no unit is provided then ignore addition of unit
        if unit == '':
            name = name

        #If unit is HTML temperature character then replace with UTF-8 DegC 
        elif unit == '&deg;C':
            subunit = '\u00b0' + "C"
            name = name + ' (' + subunit + ')'

        #Carry out unit and value conversion if Speed is received
        elif unit == 'km/h':
            subunit = 'mph'
            name = name + ' (' + subunit + ')'
            value = convert_speed(value)

        #Carry out unit and value conversion if Consumption is received
        elif unit == 'l/100':
            subunit = 'mpg'
            name = name + ' (' + subunit + ')'
            value = convert_economy(value)

        #Combine name  and unit into name string
        else:
            name = name + ' (' + unit + ')'
      # Combine data to send as bytes via RS232 Comms
        textstr = bytes(name + ',' + value + "\r",format) #**This is where script 1 would contribute the remaining parts**
        ser.write(textstr)
```

(EXCUSE THE WONKY INDENTING, pasting in my code from notepad++ didnt work smoothly this time)

I am unsure whether I can create another script just for the serial communication which reads the current variables from the two scripts periodically as they internally change or not? I have only previously defined functions within one script and called them from another or just variables which remain fixed (not constantly changing like these).

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use multithreading. It sounds scary, but I think it is the cleanest way to run 2 loops at the same time.

*I am quite new with python so I can't really help you with exact solution. But I hope my idea could help you at least a little bit*

The idea is that you run script1 and script2 as secondary threads and append the outputs from them to main thread into lists.

Then the main thread combines the information and sends it to HMI.

This will work if the script 1 and 2 send information with the same frequency. If they don't you can adjust it in the main loop

```
import threading

data_1 = []
data_2 = []

def script_1():
    while True:
        # do something - your script 1
        # create textstr
        data_1.append(textstr)

def script_2():
    while True:
        # do something - your script 2
        # create textstr
        data_2.append(textstr)


# Create threads
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=script_1)
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=script_2)


# Start threads (never ending while loops)
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()


# Main loop
while True:
    if len(data_1) > 0 and len(data_2) > 0:
        # Combine data and send them to HMI
        combined_data = data_1[0] + data_2[0]
        send_to_HMI(combined_data)
        
        # Remove sent data from lists
        data_1.pop(0)
        data_2.pop(0)
```

Also this is probably very bad performance-wise. There are better ways to do this, but this is the only one I know about.